# How to implement custom commands in WebStorm?

Tags: vim, webstorm, ideavim

I want to implement my own custom command to `~/.ideavimrc` file but I could not manage it.

**~/.ideavimrc**

```
source ~/.vimrc
```

**~/.vimrc**

```
"Below command provides to quit file with uppercase Wq."
command! Wq wq

"Below command provides design recipe for methods."
command! Fcomments :r ~/Documents/vcommands/FunctionComments.txt
```

**FunctionComments.txt**

```
/**
  Data Definition: 
  Properties:
  Purpose:
  Example:
  Returns:
*/
```

What I want is when I type `Fcomments` to WebStorm as command mode, I want to upload that file to upside of my code. But `Wq` works, `Fcomments` not working why?

What I get from WebStorm is `VIM Not an editor command: r | r ~/...`

Comment: Try to remove the colon, just `r`, not `:r`. (It works in Vim with the colon, but the more correct form is without the colon, it's possible that ideavim will only work with the version without the colon.)

Comment: Hi @filbranden, with doing this I still get the same error `VIM Not an editor command: r | r ~/...`.

Comment: If you run a `:r` command (outside of an user command) does it work?

Comment: @filbranden  you mean this? `:r ~/.../exact-path-file`. when I tried this I still get `Not and editor command: r | r` from WebStorm.

Comment: That seems to be the problem then... Your ideavim is missing that Vim command... Not really sure what you can do about that... ?